# How to apply formula to new rows that are generated by script

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a spreadsheet where new data into rows is added every hour. I tried using `arrayformula` but couldn't figure out how.

Example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SQ1ACRy1I4aW9abRWP-cuV65PPNla1cC6NTycsaEizs/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to compute column `per hour`

Answer (score 0):

See Ben's solution in your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SQ1ACRy1I4aW9abRWP-cuV65PPNla1cC6NTycsaEizs/edit#gid=0):

`={ "per hour"; ArrayFormula( if( len( offset( B2:B , 1 , 0 ) ) , ( ( B$2-B3:B ) / ( A3:A - A$2 ) ) / 24 , ) ) }`